# Does any one has idea how to start consul web ui with the docker image on windows?

Tags: docker, consul

I have downloaded the Docker Consul image and it is running, but I am not able to access its web UI. Does any one have an idea how to get started. I am running this on my local machine in developer mode.

I am running:

```
docker run -d --name=dev-consul -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 consul
```

Answer (score 1):

See [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/progrium/consul/):

> The Web UI can be enabled by adding the -ui-dir flag:
>     `$ docker run -p 8400:8400 -p 8500:8500 -p 8600:53/udp -h node1 progrium/consul -server -bootstrap -ui-dir /ui`
>   We publish 8400 (RPC), 8500 (HTTP), and 8600 (DNS) so you can try all three interfaces. We also give it a hostname of node1. Setting the container hostname is the intended way to name the Consul Agent node.

You can try to activate ui by setting the `-ui-dir` flag.

Answer (score 0):

First set experimental to true in docker desktop if you're using windows containers.
[image: Docker desktop settings]

The command below will work, because you need to expose the port 8500.

`docker run -d -e CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0 -p 8500:8500 consul`

You will be able to access consul at http://localhost:8500/

You could also use a compose file like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  consul:
    image: consul
    ports:
      - "8500:8500"
    environment: 
      - CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0
    networks: 
      nat:        
        aliases:
          - consul
```